# About mongodb text index

Tags: mongodb, fulltext-index

I have created a collection articles in MongoDB with two text fields `topic` and `content` on which I have created text indexes. I have created text indexes on these two fields. However, sometimes I need to do text search on `topic`, and sometimes I need to do text search on both `topic` and `content`, so how do I write the query statements for each of them?

I want to be able to do a separate text search for a field in a text index

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Depending on the extent of your queries, I'm not sure that this can be done with self-managed `$text` queries. In some cases you could `$and` another predicate condition with a regex to see if the match is on the right field. But that requires specific types of text searching and is not a generally applicable approach. Might need to look toward alternate approaches such as Atlas Search